# android checkbox recyclerview using kotlin

Tags: android, checkbox, android-recyclerview

i wanna ask something about my code.

so, I wanna retrieve the data that i have selected in the checkbox recyclerview, and then put it into variabel arraylist. and then when i click button next, i can use variabel arraylist in main code and then i can move to next page. can you help me to add that code on my coding?

anyway i use kotlin, so i need code kotlin

here my main coding

```
 private fun getData() {
    mDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(this@ChooseCategoryActivity, ""+databaseError.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            dataCategory.clear()


            for(getdataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.i("dataKey", getdataSnapshot.key.toString())
                val kategori = getdataSnapshot.getValue(Kategori::class.java)
                dataCategory.add(kategori!!)
            }

            rv_user_kategori.adapter = UserCategoryAdapter(dataCategory) {

            }
        }

    })
```

here my adapter recyclerview

```
class UserCategoryAdapter(private var data: List<Kategori>, private var listener: (Kategori) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


lateinit var ContextAdapter : Context

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    ContextAdapter = parent.context
    val inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_row_kategori, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(inflatedView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int = data.size

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindItem(data[position], listener,ContextAdapter, position)
}

class ViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    private val namaKategori:TextView = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_row_kategori)
    var checkbox:CheckBox = v.findViewById(R.id.txt_row_kategori)


    fun bindItem(data: Kategori, listener: (Kategori) -> Unit, context : Context, position : Int) {
        namaKategori.text = data.nama

        itemView.setOnClickListener {
                listener(data)

        }
    }
}
```

}

please help me to find that solution.

Comment: Did I understand right, that you want to notify your Activity/Fragment when somebody checks or unchecked a checkbox inside your recycler view item ?

Comment: yes, like that. when i checks some items on my checkbox recyclerview i wanna get text at checkbox checks and that text move to main activity

Answer (score 0):

Your listener currently return only the `Kategori`. Make it return also the position of the item on the list and/r the status of the checkbox. You can get the state of the checkbox with `Checkbox.isChecked`.

Answer (score 0):

To use a listener you need to add `invoke`, so the flow should be :

Your adapter declaration

```
class UserCategoryAdapter(private var data: List<Kategori>, private var listener: (Kategori) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserCategoryAdapter.ViewHolder>()
```

Then in your bind you send the listener via constructor as well

```
holder.bindItem(data[position], listener,ContextAdapter, position)
```

Once you are in the `ViewHolder` and you want to detect the state change listener you need to call it like

```
itemView.setOnClickListener { listener.invoke(data) }
```

Comment: and how i take text of checkbox i checked in my main activity ?

Comment: You pass it in the invoke, right? You have the `data`

Comment: Have you solved this? In order to help other people if this helped you feel free to upvote and mark this as a correct answer. Thanks :)